# Python - use list as function parameters

Tags: python, list, function-parameter

How can I use a Python list (e.g. `params = ['a',3.4,None]`) as parameters to a function, e.g.:

```
def some_func(a_char,a_float,a_something):
   # do stuff
```

Comment: Related: [Python 3 Annotations: Type hinting a list of a specified type (PyCharm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853923/python-3-annotations-type-hinting-a-list-of-a-specified-type-pycharm)

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You can do this using the splat operator:

```
some_func(*params)
```

This causes the function to receive each list item as a separate parameter. There's a description here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Answer (score 72):

This has already been answered perfectly, but since I just came to this page and did not understand immediately I am just going to add a simple but complete example.

```
def some_func(a_char, a_float, a_something):
    print a_char

params = ['a', 3.4, None]
some_func(*params)

>> a
```

Answer (score 17):

Use an asterisk:

```
some_func(*params)
```

Comment: Along those lines, you can also use a dictionary: def f(a, b, c): #do stuff. mydict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3} f(**mydict)

Answer (score 12):

You want the [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) operator *.