# How to extract array entries for method call in python

Tags: python

I have an array that should be expanded to provide multiple arguments to a function call - like the following:

```
def x(a,b,c):
    print "%d %d %d" %(a,b,c)

t = [1,2,3]

x(t[:])  # Will not work - this is only one value
```

Basically I am looking for the python equivalent to the

```
 :_*
```

construct in scala

Comment: x(*t) is what you are looking for

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - use list as function parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979542/python-use-list-as-function-parameters)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> def x(a, b, c):
...     print(a, b, c)
...
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x(*l)
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to unpacking, you can change your function to accept a list:

```
def x(nums):
    # cut off list and join three elements
    print ' '.join(str(i) for i in nums[:3])
```