# Theano: arguments for calling Theano functions

Tags: python, numpy, theano

The nature of python makes it very hard for me to find a kind of formal definition how to call a theano function.

When given a list of matrices `batch` with length 4, I call

```
validationFunction(batch[0],batch[1],batch[2],batch[3])
```

and this works.

When I call

```
validationFunction(batch)
```

or

```
validationFunction((list(batch))
```

it complains:

```
        validationError += validationFunction(batch) # [0],batch[1], batch[2], batch[3])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 786, in __call__
    allow_downcast=s.allow_downcast)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/type.py", line 149, in filter
    converted_data = theano._asarray(data, self.dtype)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/theano/misc/safe_asarray.py", line 33, in _asarray
    rval = numpy.asarray(a, dtype=dtype, order=order)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 474, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "dummy.py:96"  at index 0(0-based)', 'could not broadcast input array from shape (7,3) into shape (7)')
```

I have a list of symbolic input variables and a corresponding list of minibatches. Batch is in the form:
        print("batch singular = \n0:{}\n1:{}\n2:{}\n3:{}".format(batch[0],batch[1],batch[2],batch[3]))

```
0:[[3.0 3.0 2.0]
 [3.0 2.0 5.0]
 [2.0 5.0 3.0]
 [5.0 3.0 4.0]
 [3.0 4.0 3.0]
 [4.0 3.0 2.0]
 [3.0 2.0 6.0]]
1:[[5.0 3.0 4.0]
 [3.0 4.0 3.0]
 [4.0 3.0 2.0]
 [3.0 2.0 6.0]
 [2.0 6.0 6.0]
 [6.0 6.0 6.0]
 [6.0 6.0 2.0]]
2:[[3.0 2.0 14.0]
 [2.0 2.0 14.0]
 [6.0 2.0 14.0]
 [6.0 2.0 14.0]
 [6.0 2.0 14.0]
 [2.0 2.0 14.0]
 [4.0 2.0 14.0]]
3:[[2.0]
 [6.0]
 [6.0]
 [6.0]
 [2.0]
 [4.0]
 [4.0]]
```

So basically, how can I call validationFunction(a[0],a[1],...,a[n-1]) without hardcoding 1...n? What *is* the definition of the arguments?

The function is defined

```
validationFunction= theano.function(inputVars + [targetVar], testLoss)
```

where inputVars is a list of theano matrices and targetVar is a theano matrix. Should I define the function in a different way? `inputVars + [targetVar]` creates a list of my three inputs and one target.

I really spent a lot of time already with theano and its style, but some things are documented much too compact.

> Inputs can be given as variables or In instances. In instances also
>   have a variable, but they attach some extra information about how
>   call-time arguments corresponding to that variable should be used.
>   Similarly, Out instances can attach information about how output
>   variables should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979542/python-use-list-as-function-parameters), I simply had to call it:

```
validationFunction(*batch)
```

instead of

```
validationFunction(batch)
```

Oh dear, the more python I learn the more I start to love all that verbose boilerplate declaration and interface defining stuff from java.