# How to Enter All List Items Into a Function as Separate Arguments?

Tags: python, list, pandas, anova

I am looping over a pandas DataFrame and trying to perform [ANOVA](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781784390150/2/ch02lvl1sec24/anova). I have the arguments to the function stored in a list, but don't know how to enter all of the list arguments into the function as separate arguments. As I am looping through many columns, the length of the list is different every time. Is there any way to do this?

What I want is this:

```
list_of_args = [array1, array2, array3]
stats.f_oneway(array1,array2,array3)
```

Comment: Will this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979542/python-use-list-as-function-parameters

Comment: This has been asked before, but you want to do `stats.f_oneway(*list_of_args)`

Comment: Thank you Imran and Evan! I just couldn't come up with the correct terms to search for no matter how I tried!!!