# Function to take a list and sort it using another function

Tags: python, list, sorting

A rather simple question but as a newbie, I can get a little lost.

How would I format my function to take a list as an input for my function, and then use another function to sort the said list?
I have a functioning code for what I underneath call func1.

```
func1 (x, list1)
    Doing code to sort list1 when x is added 

func2 (list2)
    out = []
    for i in list2:
    func1(mylist[i],out)
```

Not really sure how to define func2 to make it take a list like ex. func2([4,2,3,1]), use func1, to give [1,2,3,4].
out is in the start an empty list.
So performing func2 should first look at list[0], take that into func1(4,out) --> out = [4]
Next step, it should take list [1] = 2. func1(2, out) --> [4,2] --> [2,4].
And so on until all elements are reviewed and sorted.

If anyone has a good explanation of how to fix func2 I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: One issue here is that lists have a built-in `sort` method which is the obvious (and efficient) way to sort them. Is there a real problem that you are trying to solve, or is this just for sake of an exercise?

Comment: This should point you in a right direction
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979542/python-use-list-as-function-parameters

Comment: Exercise, so want to see if I can do this without using any imports.

Comment: Fair enough, though you certainly don't need any imports in order to call `list2.sort()` or whatever.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.Did not mean imports, but wanted to see if I could solve it without sort as well :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, `func1` should insert element `x` into the sorted `list1` at the right position so that the resulting list is still sorted?

Comment: You marked your question as `[python]`. However, the code you have shown does not really look like python. To define a function in python, the first line should be `def func1(x, l):`, not just `func1(x, l)`

Comment: It is python. Just posed it as an example, should have Been more elaborate in my writing. 

Exactly, x will be inserted into the list and put in the right position.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches when working with a list in python. You can either modify the list in-place, or you can build a new list.

Unfortunately for your "I want to do everything myself" attitude, modifying a list in-place means that you'll have to rely only on list methods, such as `.sort` or `.insert` or `.remove`. Here is a list of useful list methods: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

```py
# insert element x into sorted list l in-place
def func1(x, l):
    i = 0
    while i < len(l) and l[i] < x:
        i += 1
    l.insert(i, x)

# returns a sorted copy of list l
def func2(l):
    result = []
    for x in l:
        func1(x, result)
    return result
```

This might be disappointing to you because you were hoping to avoid relying on `.insert` to insert the element.

Now the second approach: instead of modifying the list in-place to insert an element into it, we'll return a new list, which is a copy of the original list, with the new element inserted.

```py
# return a copy of sorted list l, with x inserted
def func1(x, l):
    i = 0
    while i < len(l) and l[i] < x:
        i += 1
    return l[:i] + [x] + l[i:]

# return a sorted copy of list l
def func2(l):
    result = []
    for x in l:
        result = func1(x, result)
    return result
```

**Important note:** Take a close look at the two versions of `func2`. They are very similar, but there is an important difference between the two. Because they rely on `func1`, and we changed `func1`, we also had to change `func2`.